# Bash command to copy before cursor and paste after?

Tags: bash, command-line, clipboard, line-editor

I am not sure how to word this, but I often I find myself typing commands like this:

```
cp /etc/prog/dir1/myconfig.yml /etc/prog/dir1/myconfig.yml.bak
```

I usually just type out the path twice (with tab completion) or I'll copy and paste the path with the cursor. Is there some bashfoo that makes this easier to type?

Comment: I think you mean `bash-fu` :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are a number of tricks (there's a duplicate to be found I think), but for this I tend to do

```
cp /etc/prog/dir1/myconfig.yml{,.bak}
```

which gets expanded to your command.

This is known as [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). In the form used here, the `{}` expression specifies a number of strings separated by commas. These "expand" the whole `/etc/prog/dir1/myconfig.yml{,.bak}` expression, replacing the `{}` part with each string in turn: the empty string, giving `/etc/prog/dir1/myconfig.yml`, and then `.bak`, giving `/etc/prog/dir1/myconfig.yml.bak`. The result is

```
cp /etc/prog/dir1/myconfig.yml /etc/prog/dir1/myconfig.yml.bak
```

These expressions can be nested:

```
echo a{b,c,d{e,f,g}}
```

produces

```
ab ac ade adf adg
```

There's a variant using numbers to produce sequences:

```
echo {1..10}
```

produces

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

and you can also specify the step:

```
echo {0..10..5}
```

produces

```
0 5 10
```

Comment: damn thats sweet. I figured I wasn't the first to ask, just kind of a tricky question to word.

Comment: What does the comma do there?

Comment: See [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) in the manual: it separates values used in the expansion. Here the two values are the empty string and `.bak`.

Answer (score 12):

History expansion can be useful for this kind of thing (assuming bash history is enabled).

In your example, you could do:

```
cp /etc/prog/dir1/myconfig.yml !#:1.bak
```

Here, the `!#` refers to the current line, `!#:1` refers to parameter 1 on the current line,
and `!#:1.bak` refers to parameter 1 on the current line with '.bak' tacked onto the end.

When you have the history specifier typed out, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to expand it to its actual value if you want to e.g. double check or modify the filename.

The "History Expansion" section in the bash man pages has more info.

Answer (score 9):

Similar to progo's answer, but somewhat simpler: `C-w` cuts (“kills”) the word to the left of the cursor, `C-y` inserts (“yanks”) it again.

```
$ cp /etc/dir1/myconfig.yml█                              (C-w)
$ cp █                                                    (C-y)
$ cp /etc/dir1/myconfig.yml█                              (space, C-y)
$ cp /etc/dir1/myconfig.yml /etc/dir1/myconfig.yml█       (finish text)
$ cp /etc/dir1/myconfig.yml /etc/dir1/myconfig.yml.bak█
```

Comment: Also worth noting that you can do this with multiple words in a row (if your filename has spaces, for example) and C-y will paste all of them, as long as you haven't moved the cursor or typed anything else in between. Any mix of deletion commands _except_ single-character deletions (e.g. backspace/del/ctrl-d) works with this.

Answer (score 7):

You can also actually cut-paste (kill-yank in emacs/bash terms) from the commandline to duplicate parts for editing.

`M-d` kills forwards until word boundary, and you can kill text multiple times and they all get concatenated together to a single 'paste' for yanking. Convenient!

Yank this all back to the commandline at cursor by `C-y`. So if you have a line like this (the block element █ indicates cursor position):

```
$ cp avb.txt█                 (M-b M-b)
$ cp█avb.txt                  (M-d) kill the word 'avb'
$ cp █.txt                    (C-y) yank it back
$ cp avb█.txt                 (C-e) to the end of line
$ cp avb.txt█                 (C-y) yank it again
$ cp avb.txt avb█             finish the line
$ cp avb.txt avb.foo█
```

Either way you prefer to do it, familiarizing yourself with what bash has to offer in interactive key department will be beneficial. http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_7.html

Answer (score 6):

In `tcsh` or `zsh`, <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+_</kbd> in `emacs` mode (`copy-prev-word` widget) inserts the last word, so

```
cp very-long-path Alt+Ctrl+_.back
```

`bash` has a `copy-backward-word` widget (not bound to any key by default) but that only copies the word to the ring buffer, you'd need to also press <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> (in `emacs` mode) to yank it. But you could do:

```
bind '"\e[cpw~": copy-backward-word'
bind '"\e\C-_": "\e[cpw~\C-Y"'
```

To have <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+_</kbd> do both the copy/snarf and paste/yank like in `tcsh`/`zsh`.